# C# Coded UI - How to open a pdf file from a link in a web page

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2017, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Using Coded UI in Visual Studio 2017, how do I open a pdf file from a link in a web page?

Here is the segment of code I've written:

```
// Click on "View our documents" link
        BrowserWindow browser2 = BrowserWindow.Launch(url);
        browser2.Maximized = true;
        UITestControl rpQ3FinReport = new UITestControl(browser2);
        rpQ3FinReport.TechnologyName = "Web";
        rpQ3FinReport.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Hyperlink");
        rpQ3FinReport.SearchProperties.Add("InnerText", "2017 Q3 Financial Report");
        Mouse.Click(rpQ3FinReport);

        // Open the pdf report 
        UITestControl rpQ3FinReportPDFOpen = new UITestControl(browser2);
        rpQ3FinReportPDFOpen.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
        rpQ3FinReportPDFOpen.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Button");
        rpQ3FinReportPDFOpen.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Open");

        Mouse.Click(rpQ3FinReportPDFOpen);

        Playback.Wait(3000);
```

The above code for rpQ3FinReport clicks the link containing the PDF file, but then in the footer of the web page a message appears to either Open or Save or Cancel the pdf file.

I found the object property info for Open and used rpQ3FinReportPDFOpen to open the PDF, but **error message** states:

> Message: Test method HandCodingWebApp1.CUITHandCoding.StartURL threw
> exception:
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException:
>
> Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control.
>
> Additional Details:  TechnologyName:  'MSAA' Name:  'Open'
>
> ControlType:  'Button'  --->
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
>
> 0xF004F002

How do I resolve this issue?

I've attached an image of the web page. Please note that I had to erase some of the identifiable segment from the page.[image: webpage]

Thank you.

Comment: not to sound too mundane, but it seems like you're trying to click a button that is not visible. can you post a screenshot of your webpage?

Comment: Hi Francesco, I have added the image within the main question. The record and play option allows me open and close the PDF file, probably that will help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work for you.
It is possible the the Test is trying to click the control too fast.
Try inserting this here:

```
openButton.WaitForControlExists();
Playback.Wait(150);
Mouse.Click(openButton);
```

It waits for the control until its enabled and then clicks it.
The 150ms wait period is because the program might be too fast again.

Also, your code works for me fine. (the same code as yours without the url definition in BrowserWindow and without the clicking of the hyperlink):

```
BrowserWindow browserWindow = new BrowserWindow();

// Open the pdf report 
UITestControl openButton = new UITestControl(browserWindow);
openButton.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
openButton.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Button");
openButton.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Open");
Mouse.Click(openButton);
```

You could also try this here where I am defining the browserWindow control myself:

```
UITestControl browserWindow = new UITestControl();
BrowserWindow.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
BrowserWindow.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Window");
BrowserWindow.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName", "IEFrame");

// Open the pdf report 
UITestControl openButton = new UITestControl(BrowserWindow);
openButton.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
openButton.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Button");
openButton.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Open");

Mouse.Click(openButton);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response hyperionb. I will test this and will get back.

Comment: Adding a bit of wait time before clicking the file has solved the problem. Thanks hyperionb!